# Change theme without admin access

Tags: unity, themes

I am working on Ubuntu 16.04, but don't have admin access. I want to change the theme. But, I can not install Ubuntu-tweak. Is there any other way to install or change the theme to specific logged-in user only (Should not effect other users).

I found [image: this] place. From here I can change the theme. But list is limited. How can I add theme in this list also.

Comment: You want change default theme to ____ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This action can be done by using `gsettings` command which not required sudo password. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "your_theme"
```

Tested on guest session, worked.

Comment: Where I have to save this `your_theme` folder?

Comment: Thanks it work! I have to placed inside of .themes. Thank you